# Espresso - onClick does not work when performed on a nested ButtonView inside a Compose AndroidView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso

I'm using Espresso to test a Compose screen that has a nested ButtonView in an AndroidView composable. However calling `Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText("Click me")).perform(ViewActions.click())` does not work and the onClick callback is not called when the test is run, leading to the assertion to check if `text` has been updated to fail.

My compose/testing dependencies are

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.1.1"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.1.1"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.1.1"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.1.1"
```

**My hybrid Compose code looks like this**

```
// OnClick functionality works when  running app
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SampleAppTheme {
                HybridSampleScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HybridSampleScreen() {
    var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("Initial Text") }
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
    ) {
        Column() {
            ComposableWithAndroidButton {
                text = "I've been clicked"
            }
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposableWithAndroidButton(onButtonClick: () -> Unit) {
    Column() {
        Text(text = "Hello World")
        AndroidView(factory = { context ->
            //This is an alias so I can use Button view and Button Composable in the same file
            ClassicViewButton(context).apply {
                setOnClickListener { onButtonClick.invoke() }
                text = "Click me"
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Failing Test**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun testAndroidViewButtonInComposable() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            SampleAppTheme {
                HybridSampleScreen()
            }
        }

        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Hello World").assertIsDisplayed()
        // The first two assertions pass so it looks like Espresso is aware that there is a clickable Button view
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText("Click me")).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText("Click me")).check(matches(isClickable()))
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText("Click me")).perform(ViewActions.click())

        composeTestRule.waitForIdle()

        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("I've been clicked").assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}
```

To sanity-check I also created a Screen that's fully using Composables and created a test for it and that passes for me.

**Full Compose Screen**

```
@Composable
fun FullComposeScreen() {
    var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("Initial Text") }
    Column {
        ComposableWithComposeButton {
            text = "I've been clicked"
        }
        Text(text = text)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposableWithComposeButton(onButtonClick: () -> Unit) {
    Column() {
        Text(text = "Hello World")
        Button(onClick = {
            onButtonClick.invoke()
        }) {
            Text(text = "I'm a composable click me")
        }
    }
}
```

**Passing Test**

```
@Test
fun testFullComposeButtonInComposable() {
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        SampleAppTheme {
            FullComposeScreen()
        }
    }

    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Hello World").assertIsDisplayed()

    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("I'm a composable click me").assertIsDisplayed()
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("I'm a composable click me").assertHasClickAction()
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("I'm a composable click me").performClick()

    composeTestRule.waitForIdle()

    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("I've been clicked").assertIsDisplayed()
}
```

Comment: Looks like an bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215231631